# Criar novas colunas de dados em um data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Gostaria de criar 2 novas colunas no meu data frame "Mínimo" e "Máximo", em que o valor dessas colunas depende da coluna "Grupos de área total", em que por exemplo, quando "Grupos de área total"= "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha, a coluna "Mínimo" deve ser igual 0 e a coluna "Máximo" igual à 0,1ha.

Veja o resultado do comando dput(head(censo2):

```
    dput(head(censo2))
    structure(list(UF = c("Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", 
    "Rondônia", "Rondônia"), `Direção dos trabalhos do estabelecimento agropecuário` = c("Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
    "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
    "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
    "Produtor(a) titular diretamente"), `Grupos de área total` = c("Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha","De 0,2 a menos de 0,5 ha", "De 0,5 a menos de 1 ha", "De 1 a menos de 2 ha", "De 3 a menos de 4 ha", "De 1 a menos de 2 ha", "De 2 a menos de 3 ha", "De 3 a menos de 4 ha", "De 5 a menos de 10 ha", "De 4 a menos de 5 ha", "De 10 a menos de 20 ha", "De 20 a menos de 50 ha", "De 50 a menos de 100 ha", "De 100 a menos de 200 ha", "De 200 a menos de 500 ha", "De 500 a menos de 1.000 ha", "De 1.000 a menos de 2.500 ha", "De 2.500 a menos de 10.000 ha", "De 10.000 ha e mais"), `Utilização das terras` = c("Lavouras - permanentes", 
    "Lavouras - permanentes", "Lavouras - temporárias", "Lavouras - temporárias", 
    "Lavouras - área para cultivo de flores", "Pastagens - naturais"
    ), `Utilização das terras (1)` = c("Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", 
    "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Pastagens "), `Utilização das terras (2)` = c(" permanentes", 
    " permanentes", " temporárias", " temporárias", " área para cultivo de flores", 
    " naturais"), `Condição legal do produtor` = c("Produtor individual", 
    "Condomínio, consórcio ou união de pessoas (inclusive casal, quando os dois forem responsáveis pela direção)", 
    "Produtor individual", "Condomínio, consórcio ou união de pessoas (inclusive casal, quando os dois forem responsáveis pela direção)", 
    "Produtor individual", "Produtor individual"), `Nº dos estabelecimentos agropecuários com área (Unidade)` = c("29", 
    "4", "46", "6", "8", "5"), `Área dos estabelecimentos agropecuários (hectares)` = c("X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "X", "X")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 17L, 
    25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: E  a coluna `Máximo` deve ser igual à string `"0,1ha"`? E quando a coluna `Grupos de área total` **não** for igual a esse valor? `Mínimo` e `Máximo` são iguais a `NA` ou a quê?

Comment: sim, mínimo=0 e máximo= 0,1ha

Comment: Informe o resultado do comando unique(censo2$`Grupos de área total`), para que possamos ver os valores distintos da variável.

Answer (score 3):

Você deve primeiro criar as duas variáveis:

```r
censo2$Minimo <- NA
censo2$Maximo <- NA
```

Existem algumas maneiras de aplicar a condição que você deseja. Uma forma clara (talvez não a mais rápida) é através de um loop for.

```r
for(i in 1:nrow(censo2)) {
  if(censo2$`Grupos de área total`[i] == "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha") {
    censo2$Minimo[i] <- "0"
    censo2$Maximo[i] <- "0,1 ha"
  } else {
    censo2$Minimo[i] <- "???"
    censo2$Maximo[i] <- "???"
  }
}
```

Você informou que, quando o valor da variável **Grupos de área total** for igual a **Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha**, a variável **Minimo** deve assumir o valor **0** e a variável **Maximo** deve assumir o valor **0,1 ha**, entretanto, não informou o que acontece com elas quando esta condição for falsa. No código acima, elas irão receber o valor **???**, mas você pode alterar conforme a necessidade. Caso a intenção seja manter os **NAs**, basta remover a instrução else, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```r
for(i in 1:nrow(censo2)) {
  if(censo2$`Grupos de área total`[i] == "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha") {
    censo2$Minimo[i] <- "0"
    censo2$Maximo[i] <- "0,1 ha"
  } 
}
```

Caso deseje incluir múltiplas condições, basta você ir adicionando novos "else if", veja o exemplo:

```r
for(i in 1:nrow(censo2)) {
  if(censo2$`Grupos de área total`[i] == "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha") {
    censo2$Minimo[i] <- "0 ha"
    censo2$Maximo[i] <- "0,1 ha"
  } else if(censo2$`Grupos de área total`[i] == "De 0,1 a menos de 0,2 ha") {
    censo2$Minimo[i] <- "0,1 ha"
    censo2$Maximo[i] <- "0,2 ha"
  } else if(censo2$`Grupos de área total`[i] == "De 3 a menos de 4 ha") {
    censo2$Minimo[i] <- "3 ha"
    censo2$Maximo[i] <- "4 ha"
  }
}
```

Eu poderia sugerir uma maneira mais dinâmica, mas para isso eu precisaria conhecer melhor o seu dataset.

Comment: Eu tiraria o ramo `else`, o valor `NA` pode ser processado pelo R muito mais naturalmente.

Comment: Eu coloquei o else propositalmente, de modo que ela possa atribuir a condição desejada.

Comment: A minha base de dados é muito grande, por isso não apareceu todas as variáveis da coluna "Grupo de área total", como eu tenho outro valores como "De 0,1 a menos de 0,2 ha", "De 3 a menos de 4 ha", como posso colocá-los neste comando?

Comment: @IngledSeiévini E o que quer fazer com esses novos valores? O melhor é editar a pergunta com essa informação.

Comment: Editei, coloquei todos os valores da coluna

Comment: @IngledSeiévini, acrescentei um exemplo com múltiplas condições.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer o que a pergunta pede da seguinte maneira completamente vetorizada.
Esta maneira utiliza o pacote `stringi`.

```
library(stringi)

censo2$Minimo <- NA
censo2$Maximo <- NA
grupos <- unique(censo2[['Grupos de área total']])

Min <- stri_extract_first(grupos, regex = "[[:digit:]\\.,]+")
Max <- ifelse(grepl('menos', grupos),
              stri_extract_last(grupos, regex = "[[:digit:]\\.,]+"),
              "mais"
              )
i <- match(censo2[['Grupos de área total']], grupos)
censo2$Minimo <- Min[i]
censo2$Maximo <- Max[i]
```